# Tkinter treeview - how to add a icon at the beginning of text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, icons

We're all familiar with the treeview of modern computers. I want to add this look to my tkinter app using treeview to highlight what is a file and what is a folder by an image, followed by its name. But how do i do that?

What I want:

[image: This is what I want:]

What I've got:

[image: What I currently have]

This is two lines that i tried, but gave me errors.

```
folderLogo = tkinter.BitmapImage(file="icons/folder24.xbm")

self.treeOMine.insert(parent='', index=END, iid=rowid, text=path, tags=('even',), image=folderLogo)
```

I've also tried bmp ang png files, before i noticed xbm was what i needed.

I can see it mentioned everywhere, but I just cant seem to figure out how to proceed with it. Or am I misunderstanding anything here?

Quote: "Normally, you'll also specify the name of each item, which is the text displayed in the tree. Other options allow you to add an image beside the name, specify whether the node is open or closed, etc." (https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Also https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html mentions the possibility of adding image. Which makes me really think it is possible.

[image]

Comment: What is the error when you tried the `image` option? Post the full error traceback.

Comment: Have you tried using `tkinter.PhotoImage` instead of `tkinter.BitmapImage`? If so, what error messages/problems did you have?

Comment: Problem identified! The problem was that the image variable wasnt preceded by "self.".. I've been really struggling with the structure of this program with some nested functions in a class etc. What made it hard to debug from the start was that it accepted the variable with the wrong extension, but with error (without self), but when using the correct ext it showed an "unresolved reference" - NameError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `image` option, and provide an instance of `PhotoImage`:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

folder_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="folder.png")
file_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="page.png")

folder_a = tree.insert("", "end", text="Folder A", image=folder_image)
tree.insert(folder_a, "end", text="File 1", image=file_image)
tree.insert(folder_a, "end", text="File 2", image=file_image)
tree.insert(folder_a, "end", text="File 3", image=file_image)
```

[image]