How to display an image in the first colum of TreeView
I'm working on a Python application using Tkinter that includes a ttk.Treeview widget with two columns: "Streamer Name" and "Status". Each row in the treeview represents a streamer, and I want to enhance it by displaying an image in the first column alongside each streamer's name.
Here's what I have so far:
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Function to update the table with live status
def update_table():
    # Example data (replace with your own logic)
    streamers = [
        {"name": "Streamer1", "status": "Live"},
        {"name": "Streamer2", "status": "Offline"}
    ]

    for streamer in streamers:
        streamer_name = streamer["name"]
        status = streamer["status"]
        logo_path = f"assets/logos/{streamer_name}.jpg"
        
        # Insert item into treeview
        item_id = tree.insert("", "end", values=(streamer_name, status))
        
        # Display image if available
        if os.path.exists(logo_path):
            logo = Image.open(logo_path)
            logo = logo.resize((50, 50))
            logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
            tree.image_names[streamer_name] = logo  # Store reference to image
            tree.set(item_id, column="#0", value=logo)  # Error occurs here

# Create main application window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("Streamer Status")

# Create frame to hold treeview
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create treeview
columns = ("Streamer Name", "Status")
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=columns, show="headings")
tree.heading("Streamer Name", text="Streamer Name", anchor="w")
tree.heading("Status", text="Status", anchor="w")
tree.column("Streamer Name", anchor="w", width=200)
tree.column("Status", anchor="w", width=100)

# Store references to loaded images
tree.image_names = {}

# Add vertical scrollbar
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

# Place treeview and scrollbar
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

# Example of adding streamer data
update_table()

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()

The issue I'm facing is when trying to set the image (logo) in the first column (#0) using tree.set(item_id, column="#0", value=logo), I get the following error: _tkinter.TclError: Display column #0 cannot be set. I need help understanding how to correctly display images alongside each streamer's name in the ttk.Treeview widget.
Here is how it looks now:


Does this answer your question? Python Tkinter Treeview add an image as a column value

Not really because I would like to add an image in a column that also has text so there wont be another column for image

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763213/tkinter-treeview-how-to-add-a-icon-at-the-beginning-of-text

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

there was no error

it seems tkinter doesn't allow to set column #0 and you have to add image in insert(). And it may need also to remove show="headings" to show column #0

Column #0 has special meaning and it has text and image but it doesn't have value.
And set() is for changing value in other columns.
To change image or text in #0 you need
tree.item(item_id, image=logo)  # , text="Hello")

And it needs to remove show="heading" to show column #0
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=columns) #, show="headings")


BTW: And you have to change height for rows to see full image
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=50)


Full working code:
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Function to update the table with live status
def update_table():
    # Example data (replace with your own logic)
    streamers = [
        {"name": "Streamer1", "status": "Live"},
        {"name": "Streamer2", "status": "Offline"}
    ]

    for streamer in streamers:
        streamer_name = streamer["name"]
        status = streamer["status"]
        logo_path = f"assets/logos/{streamer_name}.jpg"
        
        # Insert item into treeview
        item_id = tree.insert("", "end", values=(streamer_name, status))
        
        # Display image if available
        if os.path.exists(logo_path):
            logo = Image.open(logo_path)
            logo = logo.resize((50, 50))
            logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
            tree.image_names[streamer_name] = logo  # Store reference to image
            #tree.set(item_id, column="#0", value=logo)  # Error occurs here
            tree.item(item_id, image=logo)  # <--- fixed

# Create main application window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("Streamer Status")

# Create frame to hold treeview
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create treeview
columns = ("Streamer Name", "Status")
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=columns) #, show="headings")  # <--- fixed

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=50)

tree.heading("Streamer Name", text="Streamer Name", anchor="w")
tree.heading("Status", text="Status", anchor="w")
tree.column("Streamer Name", anchor="w", width=200)
tree.column("Status", anchor="w", width=100)

# Store references to loaded images
tree.image_names = {}

# Add vertical scrollbar
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

# Place treeview and scrollbar
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

# Example of adding streamer data
update_table()

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()


If you want streamer name in the same column as image
then you have to set it as text, not value
item_id = tree.insert("", "end", text=streamer_name, values=(status,))

You need to change headers
tree.heading("#0", text="Streamer Name", anchor="w")
tree.heading("#1", text="Status", anchor="w")

